# How to send Ethereum to smart contract address without using keyword "payable"?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, payable, keyword

I have tried to send Ethereum from my wallet to the smart contract address by using the below code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.10;

contract NoUsePayable {
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract selfDestruct {
    function kill(address payable addr) public payable{
        selfdestruct(addr);
    }
}
```

However, this way still uses the `payable` keyword. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order for a smart contract to receive Ether from any kind of account, it has to have a payable function, otherwise it won't be able to receive coins.

Answer (score 0):

In general, cannot send ETH to a smart contract that does not have the `receive` function or a `payable` function.

There are two non-standard ways ways to get ETH into a smart contract:

1. Send ETH to another contract and `selfdestruct` that contract with the destination address as the address you want to send ETH to.
2. Mine a block and send the ETH reward to the address you want to send ETH to.